# While running Mongodb, getting “enabling http interface” message and stopped

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the following error when I run a freshly installed MongoDB:

```
$ mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:/mongodb/data/db --logpath c:/mongodb/log/mongodb.log --logappend --rest   
2015-03-17T17:32:55.359+0530 ** WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface   
2015-03-17T17:32:55.360+0530 ** enabling http interface
```

Can you help me to fix it?

I am using windows 7 machine

Comment: Does the WARNING make you want to change the command line arguments?

Comment: There are questions and answers on stackoverflow.com which deal with this; for example [Question 28446080](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446080/mongodb-warning-rest-is-specified-without-httpinterface)

Answer (score 1):

The REST API (`--rest`) depends on the HTTP interface (`--httpinterface`) so the warning here is that the HTTP interface is being enabled for you automatically in order to support REST.

Both the REST API and the HTTP interface are strongly discouraged outside of trusted development environments as they are not secure. Starting from MongoDB 2.6, both of these options are disabled by default.

See also: [Network Exposure and Security](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-network/) and the [MongoDB Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/).